# Question about the ideas behind conditioning on sigma algebras

Tags: probability, probability-theory

It is often said, when introducing conditional expectation with respect to a sigma algebra, that one is "taking what happened in the past into account" - think filtration. I cannot reconcile this claim with the fact that if a sigma algebra contains one event, it contains also its complement. In what way does a filtration "take the past into account"? Any illuminating example?

Comment: If a sigma algebra is generated by one event, it means you know all the info about that event. In particular, you can answer the question - did the event happen? With that in mind, you can also answer the converse - did the event not happen? This is the information given by the complement.

Comment: Can you expand on this? A sigma algebra generated by one event will be something like $A$, $A^c$,$\Omega$, $\emptyset$. In what sense does this tell me if $A$ happened or $A^c$ happened?

Comment: Conditioning on a sigma algebra $\mathcal{G}$ in some sense means that you have knowledge of everything related to $\mathcal{G}$. In particular, the sigma algebra generated by a single measurable set is the sigma algebra generated by its indicator function $\mathcal{1}_A$, which is $1$ when $A$ occurs and $0$ when $A^c$ occurs. Thus, if you observe the indicator function, you can answer the question whether $A$ or $A^c$ occurs.

Comment: I am sorry but I still find this elusive. What does it mean to "observe" a function?

Comment: One has a sample space $\Omega$ which represents all possible states of the world. Let us assume that as of now, our sample point/state is $\omega \in \Omega$. We would like to learn more about this state, so we measure certain things about it by using random variables to answer certain questions and eliminate certain sample points in the space. To do this, we observe some random variable $X$, for example, $X$ could be the current temperature of a room.

Comment: Once we observe this random variable, we can make certain deduction about the sample point/state the world is in - for example, if we observe that the temperature is some value $T$, we see that our sample point lies in the preimage $X^{-1}({T})$, and thus on the basis of this information, eliminate certain sample points from this space (all sample points with temperatures not equal to $T$).

Comment: This is clear but this is not what is usually done in my experience. Usually you condition on sigma algebras generated by random variables $X_0,X_1,..X_n$, you have no information like looking at a specific $X_i^{-1}$ of some $x$.

Comment: The sigma algebra generated by the past random variates in fact contains the information of singletons. It contains preimages of *all Borel-measurable* sets! It's just wrapped up into the notation $\sigma(X_1, \cdots, X_n)$. In particular for any $x$ and $i$ we have $X_i^{-1}(\{x\}) \in \sigma(X_1, \cdots, X_n)$.

Comment: Exactly, it contains all of them.